# How can i prevent buttons of video.js submit form?

Tags: jquery, forms, video.js

In my web-application i have a video.js-player which is integrated in a form with a checkbox to mark uploaded video as deleted. My problem is that all buttons of the player submit form. How can i prevent that behaviour?

Extract (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLsvLv0q/11/ ):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#f_produkt").submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("submit");
    });
});

<form id="f_produkt" action="" method="post">
Delete? <input id="f_delete" type="checkbox" value="1" name="delete">
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{}'>
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
<input id="f_submit" type="submit" value="Only this button to submit the form">
</form>
```

EDIT: video.js fixed the problem https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/2471

Comment: Not on Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I have the problem in Firefox 40 and Chrome 44 too (Windows 8.1). Have you clicked on the play button or on the video-canvas?

Comment: Yes it submits the alert and plays the video, nothing more.

Comment: But i only want that behaviour for my "f_submit" and not for all buttons. Perhaps i should report that problem to video.js on github, so they add type="button" for all of their buttons?

Answer (score 1):

well u can check for which button is clicked so u can trigger your action

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#f_produkt").submit(function(e)
    {
        var check = $("#f_submit").data('clicked');
        if(check == 'Y'){
            $("#f_submit").data('clicked','N');
            alert("submit");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $("#f_submit").on('click',function(){
        $(this).attr('data-clicked','Y');
    });
});
```

hope this is the solution you are looking for just figure out on which click you want your action....

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, but video.js fixed the bug: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/2471

Comment: most wellcome. nice if they have fixed the bug

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IE you need `event.returnValue`, try this:

```
$("#f_produkt").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    alert("submit");
});
```